# Yum Update Broke Slapd

Tags: centos, openldap

First, I am not an OpenLDAP expert.

I have openldap (`slapd`) running on a server that has been working for years.  Today, I ran `yum update` and it updated quite a few packages, including the openldap packages.  Once it finished (without errors) our LDAP server was not running.  I attempted a simple `service slapd start` (and `/etc/init.d/slapd start`) both of which suddenly fail.

If I look in the `/var/log/ldap.log` file, I see these entries:

```
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.40 (May 10 2016 23:30:49) $#012#011mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.40/openldap-2.4.40/build-servers/servers/slapd
read_config: no serverID / URL match found. Check slapd -h arguments.
slapd stopped.
connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
```

Both `slaptest` and `slaptest -u` are successful:

```
# slaptest
config file testing succeeded
# slaptest -u
config file testing succeeded
```

Here are the openldap version(s):

```
openldap-clients-2.4.40-12.el6.x86_64
openldap-servers-2.4.40-12.el6.x86_64
openldap-devel-2.4.40-12.el6.x86_64
compat-openldap-2.3.43-2.el6.x86_64
openldap-2.4.40-12.el6.x86_64
```

Here is also my `slapd.conf` file that worked prior to the yum update:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/passwordSelfReset.schema

allow bind_v2

pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap

moduleload syncprov.la
moduleload unique.la

database monitor
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
        by dn.exact="cn=admin,dc=am5up,dc=com" read
        by * none

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=am5up,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=admin,dc=am5up,dc=com"
rootpw {SSHA}0yFFC0BTYdZLDRNtSHVz1I6YC4zJ3Z0AZ09123
directory   /var/lib/ldap

index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber               eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub

overlay unique
unique_attributes mail

ServerID        1 "ldap://ldap.am5up.com"

overlay         syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint     10 1
syncprov-sessionlog     100
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

## Host IDs in conf and script must match

For anyone else with this issue: I have figured out the problem.  During the upgrade the slightly newer version requires the host to match the server definition in the config file.

For instance, in your `slapd.conf` file has a line like:

```
ServerID 1 "ldap://myldapserver"
```

Then your startup script (or when you startup slapd) you must define the host as "ldap://myldapserver".

This would appear to make sense; however, through my troubles today I learned that the default `/etc/init.d/slapd` file that was added during my initial install lists the host as blank.  Thus, the default startup script, basically, executes:

```
slapd -h "" -u <user> -g <group>
```

Once I edited the startup script to ensure the `-h` switch on `slapd` matches what is in my config file everything started working again.